# Velocityjs giving syntax error when css "left" parameter is a percentage

Tags: javascript, css, velocity.js

This works:

`Velocity(document.getElementsByClassName('center')[0], { left:50 }, { duration: 1000 });`

This doesn't:

`Velocity(document.getElementsByClassName('center')[0], { left:50% }, { duration: 1000 });`

With this I get 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

I need to animate this such that the css `left` property is 50%. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out.

Solution was to put "50%" in quotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to `50%` as a string, so you should wrap with quotes like `{ left:'50%' }` or `{ left:"50%" }`.

Full example:

```
Velocity(document.getElementsByClassName('center')[0], { left:'50%' }, { duration: 1000 });
```